# Custom TableViewCell indent issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview

So I've got a custom tableviewcell set up with a NIB for the layout.
Inside the cell I have 2 imageviews, and when I go to delete a record, both the images indent, and I can't figure out for the life of me how to stop them from doing it.

Again, these are imageviews laid out in IB, not through a Rect.

I know

```
shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

only applies to the default types so no help there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IB you can set a view for the cell's backgroundView property. Have you done this? Are the UIImageView instances subviews of the backgroundView?

backgroundView should stay the same regardless of what's happening with the accessoryView.

Comment: That did the trick, though I didn't need to set the backGroundView. I just placed my imageViews in a view, which is in turn a subview of the tableviewcell. Cheers!